# How to check form input in html form control

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have an html file which contains a form.  There is lots of text typed input control need customer to input information.  How do I check whether the customer's input is correct?
For example, I want to check if the username only contains digits, letters and '_'.

Please help me.

I'd appreciate if somebody can provide me a demo.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would like to mention, that you should never validate input clientside. It is as secure as no validation since an attacker can modify the Code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here’s one possible approach, for a simple task like the one given as example:

```
<script>
function check(elem) {
  if(elem.value.match('^' + elem.getAttribute('pattern') + '$')) {
    return true;
  } else {
    alert(elem.getAttribute('data-msg'));
    return false;
  }
}
</script>
<input name=username pattern=[a-zA-z0-9_]{1,9} onblur=check(this)
  data-msg="The user name may only contain letters A–Z, digits, and underlines and must be 1 to 9 characters.">
```

The idea here is to start with the HTML5 pattern attribute, specifying the allowed pattern of data as a regular expression. It already works on several modern browsers and does no harm when it doesn’t. Then you add an event attribute, which causes a JavaScript-driven check to be made, using the regular expression taken from the same attribute (with a prefix and postfix character added so that the check is made on the input item as a whole).

You may wish to display the error message in some less disruptive manner than via alert()

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="username" />
<span id="invalidMessage" style="display:none; color:Red"><img src="../../Images/error.gif" alt="OK" />invalidEmail。</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#username').blur(function() {
            $('#invalidMessage').hide();
              if ($('#username').val() != "") {
                var email = /_*\w+(-?\w+)*@_*\w+(-?\w+)*(._*\w+(-?\w+)*)*.\w*/;
                if (!email.test($('#username').val())) {
                    $('#invalidMessage').show();
                 }
              }
          });         
    });
</script>
```

There is a demo,hope can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this on the client side;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

function validate_form ( )
{
    valid = true;

if ( document.contact_form.contact_name.value == "" )
  {
    alert ( "Please fill in the 'Your Name' box." );
    valid = false;
  }

    return valid;
}

//-->
</script>
```

Then, i would use more robust error checking on the server side to ensure you have valid data.  If you can catch bad data at the client, its a plus, as it avoids the hit on the server, but the validation really belongs on the data on the server side, as its more secure and can be reused by other forms.